# How do I use JOptionPane and the showMessageDialog as a debugging tool in a Java Application?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, joptionpane

I'm currently trying to modify an existing Java application. What I'd like to do is simply display pop-up "hi" alert boxes wherever I please. But it's not letting me do that.I think the first step is to import, like this:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Then, I go inside a class and put this code:

```
        //custom title, warning icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(  frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "random warning",     JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

But I get this error:

```
error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(String,String,int)
```

Shouldn't I be able to put this anywhere and it will pop-out the message? I'm not sure where the `frame` variable comes from though. Any tips appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: OY! i think i forgot to extend JPanel.. let mesee

Comment: whats happened if you test that with null instead of  frame, rest is up to you (about frame), is about your debugging in accesible and  intialized methods or classes

Comment: The frame is supposed to be an instance of a `Component` or any of its subclasses. It can also be `null` if you don't have any GUI. But the simplest way to debug an application is to use an IDE such as Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ... and use its debugger.

Comment: The stated output (having 3 arguments) could not be produced by the stated input (which has 4 arguments).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Copy/paste output.